# reverse nslookup attach arpa zone to response

Tags: bind, reverse-dns, named-conf

I have an issue that some reverse (PTR) resolution reattach in-addr.arpa zone to response.This is something wrong in the named(bind9) configuration.

Now is :

```
command : dig -x 10.1.1.107 @dns_server_ip

;; ANSWER SECTION:
107.1.1.10.in-addr.arpa. 3600 IN    PTR     myhost.mgmt.domain.eu.1.1.10.in-addr.arpa.
```

How should be :

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
107.1.1.10.in-addr.arpa. 3600 IN    PTR     myhost.mgmt.domain.eu
```

Can you suggest which config files can produce this wrong output ?
Or which config files to lookup ?
Thanks

Comment: Show your zone file

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have in your zone something like this:

```
...
$ORIGIN 1.1.10.in-addr.arpa.
...
107 3600 IN PTR myhost.mgmt.domain.eu
...
```

Notice that ORIGIN is appended to each and every *relative* name in the zone (defined below the line where origin was set), including names that appear to the right in the data of PTR, MX, NS, SRV, CNAME (and possible other) records.

If you want some names to not to append ORIGIN, you should end that name with the dot. The dot at the end of name in DNS indicates this is *absolute* name, rather than relative:

```
...
$ORIGIN 1.1.10.in-addr.arpa.
...
107 3600 IN PTR myhost.mgmt.domain.eu.
...
```